# How to close in vim all folds which do not contain folds

Tags: vim, folding

I know following options: `foldlevel, foldminlines, foldnestmax`

and the commands `zM, zm` for adjusting the fold level

But none of them allows me folding all folds which do not contain themself folds or vice versa if all folds are closed, open all which do contain themself folds

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right; there's nothing built-in. You'd have to write such yourself.

Comment: Too bad. Can you point me into a direction where I can start with?

Comment: @Hotschke: `:help folding-functions`